# Inputting a parameter for a for loop | Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a multithread that will display all the even numbers, then odd numbers, from 0 - 30. My question is, how can I use my `x` variable to set what `i` is equal to?

```
import java.util.*;

class multiThread implements Runnable {

   multiThread(int a) {
      int x = a;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
        for(int i=x; i<=30;i=i+2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
      }catch(Exception e){

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Declare `x` as a private field of the class, instead of a local variable of the constructor.

Comment: If you don't know how to use instance fields yet, what the difference between a field and a local variable is, and what the Java naming conventions are, you shouldn't even think about multithreading, which is a complex, advanced topic, requiring expertise. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `int x` variable as a class variable like this,

```
private int x;
```

This `int x` local variable can't access on for loop block

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'int x' is define in function 'multiThread(int a)',
So you can only use it belong its own scope.
I think you'd better define the variable 'int x' in class scope.